# Why one line if statement doesn't give the excepted result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use one line if condition in my program but it doesn't show me the string after else and I think it's because of the statement being True and the program thinks that the codes after else must be executed if the statement is false.

```
In [506]: string = "wow"

In [507]: string = string + "omg" if string == "wow" else "" + "why this doesn't get added?" if 1 == 1 else ""

In [508]: string
Out[508]: 'wowomg'
```

I want the `string` to be `'wowomgwhy this doesn't get added?'`

Comment: `string = string + "omgwhy this doesn't get added?" if 1 == 1 else ""` ?

Comment: string is equal to 'wow' so why do you expect the else statement to execute??

Comment: When stringing together conditions and assignments you should be acutely aware of operator precedence ...

Comment: Either you learn the precedence order of operators by heart, or you use parentheses. I'd say use the latter, because then other people don't need to remember the precedence order.

Comment: @MichaelEkoka tru dat. and, quoting the Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to do with operator precedence, the entire `+` is evaluated before the first `if-else`.

try this

```py
string = "wow"
string = (string + "omg" if string == "wow" else "") + ("why this doesn't get added?" if 1 == 1 else "")

print(string)
```

Output:

> wowomgwhy this doesn't get added?

your original code is equivalent to

```
string = (string + "omg" if string == "wow" else ("" + "why this doesn't get added?" if 1 == 1 else ""))
```